# Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))

Tags: error

I am getting this error, I have googled it but wanted some direct help as opposed to generic help... help appreciated

```
http://website.ergo.co.uk/Pages/default1.aspx
```

> Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT)) 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [COMException (0x80004004): Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80004004 (E_ABORT))]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String
>   bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet,
>   String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean&
>   pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean&
>   pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, String&
>   pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String&
>   pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, Byte&
>   pVerGhostedSetupPath, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData,
>   Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String&
>   pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32&
>   pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid&
>   pgDocId, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object&
>   pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object&
>   pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String&
>   pbstrContentTypeOrder) +0
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String
>   bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet,
>   String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean&
>   pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean&
>   pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, String&
>   pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String&
>   pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, Byte&
>   pVerGhostedSetupPath, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData,
>   Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String&
>   pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32&
>   pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid&
>   pgDocId, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object&
>   pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object&
>   pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String&
>   pbstrContentTypeOrder) +219
>
> [SPException: Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004
>   (E_ABORT))]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String
>   bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet,
>   String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean&
>   pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean&
>   pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, String&
>   pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String&
>   pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, Byte&
>   pVerGhostedSetupPath, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData,
>   Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String&
>   pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32&
>   pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid&
>   pgDocId, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object&
>   pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object&
>   pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String&
>   pbstrContentTypeOrder) +267
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebPartPageContent(Uri pageUrl, PageView
>   requestedView, HttpContext context, Boolean forRender, Boolean
>   includeHidden, Boolean mainFileRequest, Boolean
>   fetchDependencyInformation, Boolean& ghostedPage, Byte&
>   verGhostedPage, String& siteRoot, Guid& siteId, Int64& bytes, Guid&
>   docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, Byte& level,
>   Object& buildDependencySetData, UInt32& dependencyCount, Object&
>   buildDependencies, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState,
>   Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& redirectUrl,
>   Boolean& ObjectIsList, Guid& listId) +1981
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformationForInit(HttpContext
>   context, SPWeb spweb, Boolean mainFileRequest, String path, Boolean
>   impersonate, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Byte& verGhostedPage, Guid& docId,
>   UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& spLevel,
>   String& masterPageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl,
>   String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData,
>   SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, String& siteRoot,
>   String& redirectUrl, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders,
>   Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes) +718
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetFileForRequest(HttpContext
>   context, SPWeb web, Boolean exclusion, String virtualPath) +233
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.InitContextWeb(HttpContext
>   context, SPWeb web) +104
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.SPWebEnsureSPControl(HttpContext
>   context) +395
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPControl.GetContextWeb(HttpContext
>   context) +31
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.PostResolveRequestCacheHandler(Object
>   oSender, EventArgs ea) +385
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +68    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3082;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3082

Comment: Check the DB , this is mostly DB out of space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the space on your SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

the top causes of the problem being:

1 – The SQL Transaction Log database is full

2 – The windows account used to access the database doesn’t have enough permissions to the database.

Thanks,
Nidhi

Comment: I had the same; it was a Account issue. My Administrator account didn't have enough SQL-rights

Answer (score 0):

This could be a large list problem.  Do you have any really large lists that could be causing latency issues and causing the DB queries to timeout with COM?